# Salesforce Apex/JSON serialization with change on variable name

Tags: serialization, salesforce, apex

In Salesforce/Apex how can i serialize an Apex Class to Json/String with a change of variable names mapping ? like in java we can use @SerializedName annotation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please give more context: see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

So far, Apex does not support annotation for serialization. The supported annotations are
[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation.htm)

But, in this type of scenario, I always follows

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string oldA { get; set; }
    public string oldB { get; set; }
    public string oldC { get; set; }
}

String jsonStr = JSON.serialize(objectTestClass);
jsonStr = jsonStr.replaceAll('"oldA":','"newA":');
```

You can use [JSONGenerator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm) to create the output yourself

Comment: Bad idea: doing a string replace like that changes *all* occurrences of "oldA" to "newA" so you would change `{ "oldA":"oldA" }` to `{ "newA":"newA" }` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's no out of the box way for remapping variables via an annotation or a similar facility. To remap a variable you'd have to roll your own parser via [JSONParser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm) or use [untyped deserialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped) and encapsulate it into your own Apex class.